# Setting dynamic ORACLE_HOME in makefile

Tags: oracle, unix, makefile, environment-variables, solaris

So my organization is upgrading our Oracle database from 11g to 19c.

Previously, in my makefile, I had been setting ORACLE_HOME like this:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1
```

However, Oracle 19c has a fun feature that whenever they run a patch on it, the db_1 changes incrementally, becoming db_2, then db_3, with each patch, etc.

So obviously I can't hardcode the ORACLE_HOME path anymore.

In a bunch of my scripts, I'm pulling the current value from the ortab file, like this:

```
setenv ORACLE_SID DATABASE1
setenv ORACLE_HOME `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/#.*//g' | grep -w $ORACLE_SID | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`
```

And this is working just fine, pulling the correct ORACLE_HOME path from the ortab file.

However, when I tried to do this in a makefile, like so:

```
ORACLE_SID=DATABASE1
ORACLE_HOME=`cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/#.*//g' | grep -w $ORACLE_SID | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`
```

I get this error when I try to run make:

```
 $ make
 `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's//bin/proc sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=file1.pc oname=file1.c include=/path/to/include
 First RE may not be null
 *** Error code 2
 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `file1.o'
```

So obviously the command isn't working the way I'm expecting, but I am unsure how to fix it.
How do I fix the command to work inside makefile?  I'm running Solaris 11.
This is not GNU make, this is just the default make that comes with Solaris 11.

Adding more information:

My ortab file looks like this:

```
$cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab
DATABASE_TEST:/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_7:Y
DATABASE1:/opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/db_3:N
DATABASE2:/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_13:Y
DATABASE3:/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1:Y
DATABASE_PROD:/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_2:Y
```

So, what I need to do, is using the ORACLE_SID of DATABASE1, pull out the `/opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/db_3` part, to use as my ORACLE_HOME directory in the makefile.

Update:
Based on an answer below from MadScientist , this is now my makefile:

```
ORACLE_SID=DATABASE1
#ORACLE_HOME = /opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_3
ORACLE_HOME = `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w ${ORACLE_SID} | awk -F: '{print $$2;}'`

PROC=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/proc

E_INCLUDE=/path/to/include

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)

file1.o: file1.pc
        ${PROC} sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=$*.pc oname=$*.c include=${E_INCLUDE}
```

When I hardcode ORACLE_HOME, everything works correctly.

When I try to use the dynamically created ORACLE_HOME, I get this error:

```
$ make
`cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`/bin/proc sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=file1.pc oname=file1.c include=/path/to/include
 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `file1.o'
```

So it looks like it's setting ORACLE_HOME as the command itself, rather than as the result of the command.

Weirdly, when I run make print-ORACLE_HOME, I get the expected result `/opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_3`

Comment: Please post a copy of the input line that `grep` should find and the desired  final output. The pipeline could be simplified along with dropping the UUOC.

Comment: Can you just escape the hash/pound - `sed 's/\#.*//g'` (or possibly `sed 's/\#.\*//g'`)? Don't have an environment to test on, sorry.

Comment: @Milag within the ortab file is listed many ORACLE_SID variables for many databases.  So I am piping to grep the particular ORACLE_SID that I need to search for which in my base is DATABASE1.  The awk part removes the ORACLE_SID label and the :Y at the end, outputting only the ORACLE_HOME directory part of the line in the ortab file.

Comment: @bk_32 - from illumos (based on Solaris): manual for `make` shows `:sh =` and a section on Command Substitutions at this [link](https://illumos.org/man/1/make)

Comment: Ask your database administrators if they have scripts they own and maintain to setup the environment variables for each database. I'd be shocked if they don't already have a simple script named "database1" that does all of the setup work for you.

Comment: Then prepare to be shocked.  My database administrators have specifically told me that I must use the ortab file to pull the current path of ORACLE_HOME.  They are not going to update any environment variables for me, that is my responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *finally* got it to work.

Using @Milag 's answer regarding the :sh command substitution, I was able to find the documentation regarding that for Solaris (not GNU) make: [link to documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9l0/index.html#make-1s-usag-cosu)

THIS was the answer:

```
ORACLE_HOME :sh =cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}'
```

The key?  NOT putting a double dollar sign, as the documentation said:

"In contrast to commands in rules, the command is not subject for macro substitution; therefore, a dollar sign ($) need not be replaced with a double dollar sign ($$)."

Because of this I also had to hardcode `DATABASE1` instead of using the ${ORACLE_SID} variable, but since that value will never change, I can live with that.

Comment: I cannot explain why this should matter.  One or both of Solaris make or this oracle `proc` program sure is weird!

Answer (score 2):

Well, certainly this:

```
setenv ORACLE_HOME /opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1
```

could not have been in your makefile before because this is not valid makefile syntax.  Also, it surprises me that anyone is still using csh for anything, and especially scripting, in 2020.  But anyway.

The problem you're having is that makefiles are not shell scripts and the rules of syntax are different.  Of course a makefile contains shell scripts inside of it, but only in recipes: here you're setting a makefile variable.  So just plopping a shell statement down into a variable assignment very well might not work.

Here you have three problems: first, variable reference in makefiles are of the form `$(FOO)` or `${FOO}` but not `$FOO`.  Second, a `#` is considered a comment character in a makefile and must be escaped.  And finally, if you do want an actual `$` not a variable reference you have to escape it, as: `$$`.  Fixing those, this should work but note that there are likely simpler ways to do this:

```
ORACLE_SID = DATABASE1
ORACLE_HOME = `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w $(ORACLE_SID) | awk -F: '{print $$2;}'`
```

You say that after this, this rule:

```
PROC=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/proc

file1.o: file1.pc
        ${PROC} sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=$*.pc oname=$*.c include=${E_INCLUDE}
```

Gives this output:

```
$ make
`cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`/bin/proc sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=file1.pc oname=file1.c include=/path/to/include
 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `file1.o'
```

That error message is not very helpful and means nothing.  It's a shame this doesn't give a better message.

I recommend you change the rule to this:

```
file1.o: file1.pc
        echo PROC=\'${PROC}\'; ${PROC} sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=$*.pc oname=$*.c include=${E_INCLUDE}
```

then, you should see something like this in the output:

```
$ make
echo PROC=\'`cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab...lots of stuff...
PROC='/...'
 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `file1.o'
```

What you want to look at is the second line of the output, `PROC='/...'` and examine that path `/...`, whatever it is, to make sure it looks right.  Also it should not contain any whitespace or other special characters, etc.

If that value that is printed looks wrong, you'll have to fix your script to make it right.  If it looks right, then I have no idea what's going on and it must be something particular about the version of make you're using.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the original line you're right, no setenv and also should have an =.  I tried your changes but now I got a new error: `PCC-F-NOERRFILE, unable to open error message file, facility PR2
*** Error code 1`

Comment: Well, that's not an error from make so it must be from some command you're running.

Comment: Thank you for this clue, you were right, this is a Pro*C error.  Once I knew this wasn't a make error I was able to hunt down the problem.  My makefile is now running correctly with this command, thank you.

Comment: So I prematurely accepted this answer.   It's not actually working.  When I print the value for `ORACLE_HOME` from make, it prints correctly.  But when I actually run make, it's outputting this: `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}' sys_include=/usr/include lines=yes iname=file1.pc oname=file1.c include=/cm_eds/EDS_ORA/include`  So it's not actually replacing the ORACLE_HOME variable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "print the value from make"; you could have done that any one of a number of ways... which did you use?  Of course, you have assigned a _shell script_ to the variable.  The variable contains the text of the shell script.  It doesn't contain the results of _RUNNING_ the shell script.  When you use the variable in a recipe, which is running in the shell, then the shell will run the script and you'll get the output you expect.  But if you use GNU make's `info` function or similar, you'll simply see the script not its output.

Comment: If you want **make** to run the script, rather than the shell, then you have to use make's `shell` function, something like this: `ORACLE_HOME := $(shell cat /var/opt/....)`  Note very clearly here: do not use the backquotes in this version!  The `shell` function replaces the backquotes... it does the same thing for make that backquotes do in the shell.

Comment: I am not using GNU make.  I do not have GNU installed, nor can I install it.  So I cannot use the `shell` function, as that is GNU specific.  I need to find a way to have the variable contain the results of the shell script, so that when I try to use the variable, it uses the results of the script.

Comment: Why do you think that this error is due to the `ORACLE_HOME` value?  The commands that you're seeing at the command line look correct to me.  It runs a shell script, which calculates the `ORACLE_HOME` value, and invokes the `proc` function.  That must work because otherwise you'd get an error message saying "file not found" or something.  Then the command you ran exited with an exit code of 1 (not success) so make reported that failure.  It seems to me that `ORACLE_HOME` is working OK but that the command that generates `file1.o` is failing, unfortunately with no messages.

Comment: I think this because when I hardcode the ORACLE_HOME value, as I showed above, it works.  I only get this error when I try to pull the ORACLE_HOME value from the ortab file using the sed/grep/awk command.

Comment: Then, I recommend that you change your rule to add in an `echo $(ORACLE_HOME); ` into your rule before you run the `proc` so that you can see what the resulting value is.  It must be expanding to an unexpected value.

Comment: Yes, it is expanding to the entire command, replacing only the ${ORACLE_SID} portion, exactly the same as what the error message is producing: `cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`

Comment: You don't want to look at the command.  You want to look at the output that is printed.  I'll edit my answer with details

Comment: I am looking at the output that is printed, the output is the command string, and I don't know how much clearer I can be.  When I print in exactly your way, (which doesn't work mind you, you have to put an @ in front of echo inside a recipe)  I still get the same result, which is `proc = cat /var/opt/oracle/oratab | sed 's/\#.*//g' | grep -w DATABASE1 | awk -F: '{print $2;}'`, except with the backticks.  It's storing the command string in the variable and not the result.

Comment: I also don't know how much clearer _I_ can be :).  You're right, the command string is stored in the variable.  I know that.  There is NO WAY in portable make to store the _result_ in the variable.  Portable make has no facility to "run a command and store the result in a variable".  But, THAT DOESN'T MATTER.  When you use the variable in a recipe, it will be expanded TO THE COMMAND STRING.  The command string will be PASSED TO THE SHELL.  The _shell_ will run the command string and use the result in the command.

Comment: So, yes, I **know** that when you see the command printed by make it has the command string in it and not the result.  That's why I asked you to add in the `echo` command.  The text of the echo command will still contain the command string.  But the shell will run that echo command, and the result of running that echo command will be to print the result of running the command string, and then you can see whether the command string is working or not.  Also it is definitely not _required_ to prefix lines of a recipe with `@`.  In fact, it's a bad idea to do so until your makefile works.

Comment: My apologies, I see what you mean (sorry it was late on a Friday and my head wasn't in the game).  Unfortunately, it's printing what I need it to print: `PROC='/opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_3'`. If I hardcode this value as ORACLE_HOME, everything works.  But doing it this way gives me the useless makefile error.

Comment: Well, the most obvious answer is that the `proc` program, whatever it is, requires the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable to be set or else it fails with no useful error message (note, the "useless error" is not coming from make: make has no idea why the command it invoked failed or what error to print when it fails: it expects the command to generate some useful error messages about why it failed.

Comment: If you change your command to export this value, like: `export ORACLE_HOME=$(ORACLE_HOME); $(PROC) sys_include=/usr/include ...` does that help?

Comment: Not sure where to put `export ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME}`  Tried both with the semicolon and without, get `Badly formed macro assignment` no matter where I put the line, either in the definition area or in the recipe.  I have never seen a line end with ; in a makefile before.

Comment: You have: you used one with the `echo` I suggested you add :).  I mean, put it in your recipe the same way you added the `echo`.  That's just shell syntax: you can combine multiple shell commands on a single line with semicolons, like `ls; cp a b; ls; rm b; ls` or whatever.  Anyway, if that doesn't work I have no idea.  There's nothing wrong with your makefile, so it doesn't seem to be a make problem.

Comment: I just solved it!  Thank you for all your help.  I posted the solution if you are curious.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified example to start. This initial version uses `awk` to search, drops the  `sed` absent any `#` comments

```
ORACLE_SID := DATABASE1
ORACLE_HOME := $(shell awk -F: "/^$(ORACLE_SID)/ { print \$$2; }" /var/opt/oracle/oratab)
```

---

(Update)  possible Solaris version from documents, unverified:

```
ORACLE_HOME:sh = awk -F: '/^DATABASE1/ { print $$2; }' /var/opt/oracle/oratab
```

Comment: I tried this, and it's much simpler, thank you.  I got a new error now (so we're making progress): `make: Fatal error in reader: makefile, line 70: Unexpected end of line seen` (line 70 is the line where I'm trying to define ORACLE_HOME)

Comment: I also tried adding backticks instead of $(shell), but when I do that it seems to not be delineating by colon because then I get this error `sh: DATABASE1:/opt/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_3:N: not found
*** Error code 127`

Comment: Try a mini Makefile with the above 2 lines plus `$(info ORACLE_HOME "$(ORACLE_HOME)")` .  Are you running some Solaris version of `make`, not any GNU `make`?

Comment: You are not running GNU make, definitely: the error messages are totally different.  You can run `make -v` or `make --version` to try to figure out what version of make you're using, but you cannot use GNU make features like `shell`, `info`, or even `:=` (some versions of make support this but not most).  You should not be reading the GNU make manual trying to learn how to use this different version of make.

Comment: I am not running GNU make, nor did I say I was.  I do not have GNU installed, nor can I install it.  I am using whatever is the default make for Solaris10 (which does something different with a -v option than you have implied).

Comment: If you're not using GNU make then this `$(shell ...)` solution cannot work.